# Use string functions on a Const char string[]

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm attempting to make a method that will take the argument `const char string[]` from the user. this parameter. will then be outputted via a for loop to the screen character by character until the string has reached it's length.

I need to know the length of the string in order for my loop to work. for instance, if the length is 6, the loop should run 6 times, and display 6 characters onto the display.

I would have used a foreach loop for this, but I'm actually in the GBA environment and for some reason for each loops don't compile correctly. So I'm trying to use `.strlen()` instead to get the length of the string.

However, I cannot use the `.strlen()` method because my `const char string[]` isn't a string.

With all the above in mind, How can I use the `.strlen()` method in the following code?:

```
void DrawText(int x, int y, const char string[])
{


    for(int i = 0; i < string.strlen(); i++)
    {
        SetTile(0, x + i, y, 70);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::strlen(string)` from the `cstring` header, but only if `string` points to a null-terminated `char` array.